# Prolog - Search a list for an element, print the list if element is found

Tags: list, prolog

So I am trying to write a small program that does the following.

I can search for a element inside a list, if the element is found in the list, then the list is printed out to confirm that it has been found.

So in basic pseudo -

1. list of elements - computer, mouse, keyboard, webcam
2. search for mouse in this list
3. output the list which mouse has been found in

While doing some reading I found something which does what I want to do pretty much. This is below

```
on(Item,[Item|Rest]).  

on(Item,[DisregardHead|Tail]):-
on(Item, Tail).
```

If I type the query -
    on(apples, [pear, grape, banana, plum, apples]).
then it searches through the list, discarding non-relevant elements until it comes to the end and succeeds.

What I want to do is write my own list in the editor and work from it by doing the same kind of function to it like above.(Rather than just inputting the list as a query into the console.)

Thanks

Comment: Can you improve (edit) your question to clarify what is "do this from a list that I have wrote in the editor window"?

Comment: Have done, basically the code that I posted is the only thing compiled in the editor. So the query I run from console is **on(apples, [pear, grape, banana, plum, apples])**. Whereas I want to have a pre-written and compiled list to work against.

Answer (score 6):

You can define in your program

```
list_of_my_elements([pear, grape, banana, plum, apples]).

in_my_list_of_elements(X) :- 
    list_of_my_elements(L),
    member(X, L).
```

Then query

```
?- in_my_list_of_elements(apple).
```

I wouldn't re-implement and rename the member predicate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it helps a lot. If I may, can I slightly extend the question. What if I would like to physically print "Apples was found in this list" or "Apples was not found in this list"? I know about the 'write' function, but how would I use it like I said above?

Comment: If you don't want to use it in the query, I'd wrap the member function. 

member_print(X, L) :- member(X, L), write(X), write(' found in the list').

Answer (score 2):

domains
    x = integer
    l = integer*

predicates
    find(l,x)

clauses

```
find([],N) :-
    write("There is no such element in the list"),nl.

find([Element|List],1) :-
    write("The element is ",Element),nl.

find([Element|List],N) :-
    N1 = N-1,
    find(List,N1).
```

Output :

Goal: find([1,2,3,4],3)
The element is 3
Yes

Goal: find([1,2,3,4],0)
There is no such element in the list
Yes

Goal: find([1,2,3,4],5)
There is no such element in the list
Yes

Goal: find([1,2,4,3],4)
The element is 3
Yes